# Mysql UPDATE IF FIELD IS EMPTY SET VALUE ELSE CONCAT VALUE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I've a syntax error in my query:

```
UPDATE users SET name=IF(name='', 'mario', CONCAT(name, ',mario') WHERE id=1
```

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a closing bracket after CONCAT().

Your fixed query looks like this:

```
UPDATE users SET name=IF(name='', 'mario', CONCAT(name, ',mario')) WHERE id=1
```